# Two Windows/FF28.0 boxes, same page, same printer, same settings, different printout?

Tags: css, windows, firefox

I have a web page that generates barcode labels for printout.  On my development machine, a Windows Server 2003 box, I have my user's printer installed as a network printer (`\\ipaddresshere\printername`).  We have verified every single setting in the print driver's preferences to be identical.  Her box is WinXP.  Both of us are running Firefox 28.0, even with add-ons disabled (safe mode).  When I print preview, or print to her printer, the labels look right.  When she print previews, or prints to her printer, after each correct label is an entire blank label.
The full source of the page, if it makes any difference, is exactly this (unedited):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-CA"><head>
<style type="text/css">
@font-face { font-family: "Free 3 of 9 Regular"; src: url("/lib/FREE3OF9.woff"); }

.sticker { width: 2.24in; height: 0.74in; padding: 0.005in; margin: 0; top: -0.015in; position: relative; page-break-after: always; }
.partnumber, .bin_location, .description, .barcode, .lotid, .ponumber { font: 8pt Verdana; text-align: center; width: 100%; white-space: nowrap; position: absolute; }
.bin_location { text-align: left; font-weight: bold;  }
.partnumber { text-align: right; right: 0.02in; background-color: white; width: auto; }
.description { top: 9pt; }
.ponumber { font-size: 7pt; bottom: 0.02in; text-align: right; right: 0.02in; }
.ponumber:before { content: "PO "; }
.barcode { font: 32pt "Free 3 of 9 Regular"; top: 20pt; }
.barcode:before, .barcode:after { content: "*"; }
.lotid { font-size: 9pt; bottom: 0; }

body { padding: 0; margin: 0; top: 0; left: 0; position: absolute; }
        </style>
</head>
<body><div class='sticker'><div class='lotid'>0034079</div><div class='bin_location'>ACC</div><div class='partnumber'>089-08168-0002</div><div class='description'>Wave washer</div><div class='ponumber'>14-21951</div><div class='barcode'>0034079</div></div><div class='sticker'><div class='lotid'>0034080</div><div class='bin_location'>HSP (TMP)</div><div class='partnumber'>OS-TMP/PITCHSERVO</div><div class='description'>Repair Servo SN:2750</div><div class='ponumber'>14-21977</div><div class='barcode'>0034080</div></div><div class='sticker'><div class='lotid'>0034081</div><div class='bin_location'>HHK</div><div class='partnumber'>AN960-4</div><div class='description'>Washer</div><div class='ponumber'>14-22004</div><div class='barcode'>0034081</div></div><div class='sticker'><div class='lotid'>0034082</div><div class='bin_location'>HOB</div><div class='partnumber'>C21K</div><div class='description'>Compass Kit w/Fluid/Diaph/Gask</div><div class='ponumber'>14-22004</div><div class='barcode'>0034082</div></div></body>
</html>
```

Aside from our OS versions, I cannot see any difference in our setups, so why is hers printing and previewing blanks after every label, and mine not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a solution other than monkeying with the margins until hers worked and mine still did.  But I cannot explain why the two are different...